# hide placeholder text on focus

Tags: html, css

Is there a way/CSS property I can add to hide my placeholder text when in focus or when a user starts typing.
currently,  the text I enter comes on top my it while placeholder text is still in the background.
Below is my code and screenshots for the reference. Any help would be appreciated.

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field [style.width.px]=300 floatLabel="never">
    <input type="text" matInput (keyup)="searchList($event.target.value)"/>
    <span class="placeholder">{{placeHolderText()}}</span>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**CSS:**

```
.placeholder{
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 5px;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: lightgray;
}
```

Comment: That's not a placeholder its a text which you were using with class placeholder, use that on input like`placeholder="name"` [REF](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview)

Comment: @Awais correct. I had to use this to make it work for my scenario.otherwise it wasn't working with my version my angular material .that's why I am using it like this.
is there a way to hide this ?

Comment: I hope working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/o24fz5wa/11/

Comment: @LaljiTadhani Not exactly. This completely hides the placeholder text

Comment: @LaljiTadhani But I feel the solution is close to what you sent ..I need something very similar.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/o24fz5wa/12/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change top & left postion

```css
.placeholder{
  
  display:block;
  left: 20px;
  top: 15px;
  left: 5px;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: lightgray;
}

input:focus + .placeholder, input:not([value=""]) + .placeholder{
  top:-5px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field [style.width.px]=300 floatLabel="never">
    <input type="text" matInput onkeyup="this.setAttribute('value', this.value);" value="" (keyup)="searchList($event.target.value)"/>
    <span class="placeholder">{{placeHolderText()}}</span>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this -

```
<mat-form-field [style.width.px]=300 floatLabel="never">
<input type="text" matInput (keyup)="searchList($event.target.value)" placeholder="placeHolderText()" />
```

**remove the css**